# PHP Documentation inside PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there any PHP documentation inside PhpStorm like PHP Manual ?

(I mean with ability to search methods, functions, examples, etc.)

Comment: No. If you need documentation on specific function/class/etc -- place caret on such item and use `View | External Documentation`. But in general -- please describe what exactly you are after -- what exactly you need to search for etc?

Comment: You mean other than the Help menu?

Comment: I need a search box to find any method that I need and see how to use it and some little examples!!

Comment: That won't exist. What you can do is when you type in a function, say `include()`, put your cursor anywhere in the function name and go to Navigate -> Declaration, and it will take you to the definition. You can also use `View -> Quick Documentation` which will provide a link if it's a native php function.

Comment: Just to complete @aynber comment: `View -> Quick Documentation` has a convenient shortcut: `ctrl+q`.

Comment: Why not just use [the excellent PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/index.php)?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt exists bacause documentation with examples is very large and it is impossible to delivery with PHPStrom and its expensive to updated it.

My recommendation is:

1. hold `CTLR` + mouse hover over PHP function and it will show me text bubble
2. in text bubble is function description as anchor link. When you click on it it will show you simple description.
3. In simple description is `Links` with direct link to online PHP documentation to specified function